# Construct a Python class inside its method and different file

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, circular-dependency, forward-reference

I want to construct an object from the same class in one of its methods. However, the method is in a different file.
How can I do the following?

**file1.py**

```
class MyClass():
    def __init__(self, i): 
        print(i)
    from file2 import my_fun
```

**file2.py**

```
def my_fun(self):
    if i == 1:
        new_obj = MyClass(i + 1)
```

I get the following error:

```
NameError: name 'MyClass' is not defined
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! It looks like you want to attach the function to the class as basically a mixin? And the function should know which class it's been mixed into so it can create an instance of itself? May I ask why you want to do this... what problem is this supposed to solve?

Comment: Thank you for helping me to improve the question. I will add more information.

Comment: Did you plan to import `MyClass` at some point in `file2`?

Comment: He can't import MyClass there, because the function needs to be PART of MyClass.  And his syntax is valid, if unusual.

Comment: You have an unsolvable circular reference.  This simply cannot be done.  If `my_fun` needs to refer to `MyClass`, then it needs to be defined in `file1.py`.

Comment: @TimRoberts. It's quite solvable. `my_fun` does not actually need the reference to `MyClass` until it runs. Only `MyClass` needs `my_fun` up front, or nearly so. I've shown two options in my answer, one based on your original, now defunct answer, but with a more careful analysis of the execution order.

Comment: @TimRoberts. Also, you need to import `file1` into `file2` because the function references `MyClass` directly, so it needs to be imported.

Comment: @TimRoberts. Make that three distinct options. Granted all terrible and should not be done.

Comment: @RaminFakhimi. Thanks for staying responsive and fixing your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`file2` has to import `file1.MyClass` somewhere. Importing inside `my_fun` is of course possible, but not desirable. Doing `from file1 import MyClass` at the beginning of the file will cause a circular dependency problem: `MyClass` may not have been executed yet at that point, and so may not exist.

**Option 1:**

```
import file1

def my_fun(self):
    if i == 1:
        new_obj = file1.MyClass(i + 1)
```

In this case, `file1` will refer to the correct module object, even if its `__dict__` is not completely filled in at that point. By the time `my_fun` can be called, `file1` will have been loaded completely.

**Option 2:**

```
class MyClass():
    def __init__(self, i): 
        print(i)

from file2 import my_fun
MyClass.my_fun = my_fun
del my_fun
```

```
def my_fun(self):
    if i == 1:
        new_obj = MyClass(i + 1)

from file1 import MyClass
```

In this version, you place all the import statements after definitions of things imported to another file have had a chance to run. This is not very elegant at all.

**Option 3**

```
def my_fun(self):
    from file1 import MyClass
    if i == 1:
        new_obj = MyClass(i + 1)
```

This is the ugliest option of all. You remove the circular dependency by removing `file2`'s dependency on `file1`. The dependency is exclusive to `my_fun`, and does not manifest itself until runtime, when it is totally resolvable. This is not that terrible because after the first execution, the import is basically just assigning

```
MyClass = sys.modules['file1'].MyClass
```

**TL;DR**

You have a couple of ways of bypassing circular dependencies by carefully working around the execution paths of module loading. However, all options shown here are **code smell**, and you should avoid them. They indicate an inappropriate level of coupling between the modules that should be resolved in other ways.

Comment: To resolve the issue, I have moved file2 to file1.

Comment: That's the most reasonable way to do this indeed